# set info.plist file for different language

Tags: ios

I hope my app works for english and french both.
Is there a way to set info.plist file for different language?
I means that the way to set the target item 'Info.plist File'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to localise your files. Please check this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) for details about localising iOS app